# JDI: How to get the ObjectReference value?

Tags: java, jvm, jdi

I am using the JDI to recode the variable status in the method. According to the tutorial, I am not found how to get objectReference value, like List, Map or my custom class. It just can get PrimtiveValue.

```
StackFrame stackFrame = ((BreakpointEvent) event).thread().frame(0);
 Map<LocalVariable, Value> visibleVariables = (Map<LocalVariable, Value>) stackFrame
                            .getValues(stackFrame.visibleVariables());
                        for (Map.Entry<LocalVariable, Value> entry : visibleVariables.entrySet()) {
                            System.out.println("console->>" + entry.getKey().name() + " = " + entry.getValue());
                        }
}
```

if LocalVariable is PrimtiveValue type, like `int a = 10;`, then it will print

```
console->> a = 10
```

if LocalVariable is ObjectReference type, like `Map data = new HashMap();data.pull("a",10)`, then it will print

```
console->> data = instance of java.util.HashMap(id=101)
```

But I want to get result like below

```
console->> data = {a:10} // as long as get the data of reference value
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'value' of an [`ObjectReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html). It is itself an instance of [`Value`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/Value.html).

What you probably want is to get a string representation of an object referenced by this `ObjectReference`. In this case you need to call `toString()` method on that object.

Call [`ObjectReference.invokeMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html#invokeMethod(com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference,com.sun.jdi.Method,java.util.List,int)) passing a `Method` for `toString()`. As a result, you'll get a `StringReference` instance, on which you then call [`value()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/StringReference.html#value()) to obtain the desired string representation.

```
for (Map.Entry<LocalVariable, Value> entry : visibleVariables.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey().name();
    Value value = entry.getValue();

    if (value instanceof ObjectReference) {
        ObjectReference ref = (ObjectReference) value;
        Method toString = ref.referenceType()
                .methodsByName("toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;").get(0);
        try {
            value = ref.invokeMethod(thread, toString, Collections.emptyList(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }

    System.out.println(name + " : " + value);
}
```